# Angularjs debounce for multiple events not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-model

I was looking at the Angular [documentation for handling forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and found a very useful example for capturing the update in any field/control with a delay. Following is the sample code provided by Angularjs:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }" /><br />
```

It works fine. But they mentioned that `debounce` can be used with multiple events and provided another example like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 500, blur: 0 } }" /><br />
```

The problem with this example is that it always delay the updation whether you leave the field/control or not. Whereas in this case it should immediately update the model when user leave the field/control as `debounce` is **0** in case of `blur`.

[Here is link for running example in Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/haaYrc645EzP889pGe2N?p=preview)

Can anyone explain this behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you fell victim to Javascript's type conversion, specifically that `0` is `false`. Checkout the unminified source for Angular 1.3.0-beta7, line 18305:

```
var debounceDelay = ctrl.$options && (isObject(ctrl.$options.debounce)
    ? (ctrl.$options.debounce[trigger] || ctrl.$options.debounce['default'] || 0)
    : ctrl.$options.debounce) || 0;
```

Soif you have specified `options.debounce` it will try to set the `debounceDelay` first to `options.debounce.blur`, as you expected. But since this is `0` (`false`), it proceeds with the `... || ...` to `ctrl.$options.debounce['default']`, which is non-zero (`true`) and sets this value!

As a workaround, you can either specify the exact name of the event that triggers default (is it `keyup`?), or specify a small, but non-zero value for your delay, e.g. 1:

```
debounce: { default: 500, blur: 1 }
```

I think this should be filed as bug to Angular.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, but using mouseup.  I can't seem to make it work. Apparently the 'default' and 'mouseup' are incompatible. The only way I can fix it is to remove the default and break it down into the various events, such as... ng-model-options="{ debounce : {  cut: 0, paste: 0, keypress: 500, mouseup : 0, blur : 0 } }"

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was necessary to specify `updateOn` along with the `debounce` object, like so:

```
<textarea
    ng-model="$ctrl.notes"
    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 } }">
</textarea>
```